# Get only the first value from XPathNavigator?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xpath, xpathdocument

```
var xml= @"<?xml version='1.0'?>
                 <bookstore>
                 <book genre=""3"">
                   <title>The Gorgias3</title>
                   <author>
                     <name>Plato3</name>
                   </author>
                   <price>3</price>
                 </book>
            <book genre=""4"">
                   <title>The Gorgias4</title>
                   <author>
                     <name>Plato4</name>
                   </author>
                   <price>4</price>
                 </book>
            </bookstore>";



XPathDocument docNav = new XPathDocument(new StringReader(xml));
XPathNavigator navigator = docNav.CreateNavigator();
XPathNodeIterator NodeIter = navigator.Select("/bookstore/book/title");

foreach (XPathNavigator selectedNode in NodeIter)
{
    Console.WriteLine(selectedNode.Name);
}
```

How can i access straight to the first `/bookstore/book/title"` child and get his value.

I dont want to iterate and break the loop

the result should be `"The Gorgias3"`

> p.s. i dont want to modify the xpath expression with the first filter.
>
> I want to Know how i can do it with c#.

Comment: Which context are you asking the question in? -- a) knowing the '1st child' is going to be a title -- b) in such a way that you can specify what the first child is (ie title, author, ...) -- I ask because when when I examine your xml my thought without other information would be that the '1st child' is actually <book genre=""3""> and that said child has children as listed above...

Comment: Its an iterator can't it just be casted to node and used?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use:

```
var node = navigator.SelectSingleNode("/bookstore/book/title");

Console.WriteLine(node);
```

Comment: why does navigator.Select("/bookstore/book[1]/title[1]"); doesnt wrk ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir, Why? It works. It returns `XPathNodeIterator` which implements `IEnumerable`. So it returns `IEnumerable` with 1 item.